# What is a word to describe the action of someone who repeatedly says a mantra to internalize it?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word to describe the action of someone who repeatedly says a mantra to internalize it? for example "yes I can ,yes I can "

Comment: _Habituate_ is one.

Comment: I'd say that someone is *chanting*.

Comment: Look for synonyms of 'memorize'.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

[To absorb:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/absorb) :

> - To occupy the full attention, interest, or time of; engross.

or  [to assimilate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/assimilate):

> - To incorporate and absorb into the mind: assimilate knowledge.

also mental [discipline](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Discipline):

> - Mental training expected to produce a specific character or pattern of behavior, especially training that produces moral or mental improvement.

Answer (score 1):

[To recite](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recite) would describe the action of saying a mantra, and also conveys a sense of memorizing (and hence internalizing?)

> *To repeat or utter aloud (something rehearsed or memorized)*
>
> *Recitation of the formulae known as mantra.*  G. B. Sansom (1931) *Japan* iii. xii. 222, cited in ["mantra, n."](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/113726) OED Online. Oxford University Press, September 2014)

Comment: I was sure there must be a word which specifically means "a person who recites mantras" but the nearest I could find is the Tamil manthiravāthi (lit “One who says mantras” (மந்திரவாதி)), which seems to be a derogatory term for a wizard or sorcerer (see for example Nabokov, I. (2000). [Religion Against the Self: An Ethnography of Tamil Rituals](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DhTYPMsPQCIC&lpg=PA44&ots=tfW4SUNVSW&dq=%22one%20who%20says%22%20mantra&pg=PA44#v=onepage&q=%22one%20who%20says%22%20mantra&f=false):  Oxford University Press. p44) Best avoid that one!

Comment: I think you may be confusing two different things. A *mantra* (originally in Hinduism and Buddhism) is a sound repeated to aid concentration or meditation. It might for example be something like *energy has been too cheap for too long*. That is not quite the same thing as e.g. continually repeating the names pf the planets in their correct order in order to memorise them.

Comment: Hi @WS2! Were you replying to me or to the OP @Saeid? You're right that the word has accumulated a number of different meanings. I think here we have three distinct uses: 1)The 'classical' (?meaningless) aid to meditation; 2)the 'figurative' mantra often abused in proof by assertion fallacies (as in your *energy* example); and 3) the 'Oprah' mantra wherein (as in the OP's example) the specific content of the mantra is meaningful and intended to produce some change in one's behaviour, thought process etc. I was assuming the OP meant (3), but from his comment below I might have been wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I think  we can say he is inculcating,but I hear the word (inculcation) , only from psychologist and not from  ordinary people,that is why I asked the question,what do you think?thank you for the information you posted .

English definition of “inculcate”
inculcate
verb [T] uk   /ˈɪŋ.kʌl.keɪt/ formal us
› to fix beliefs or ideas in someone's mind, especially by repeating them often: Our coach has worked hard to inculcate a team spirit in/into the players.
inculcation
noun [U] uk   /ˌɪŋ.kʌlˈkeɪ.ʃən/ us
(Definition of inculcate from the Cambridge Advanced Learners Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)
What is the pronunciation of inculcate?

Comment: The word IN-cul-CATE has a negative tone. Internalizing is neutral, and means bringing the learning inside. Google defines the verb from Psychology as "make (behavior) part of one's nature by learning or unconscious assimilation.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "learning by [rote](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/rote)", where rote means:

> the process of learning something by repeating it many times instead of by understanding it.

(Macmillan Dictionary)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It will help users if you cite a source (common on this site.) I also encourage you to take the site tour and visit the help center for information on this site.

Answer (score 0):

**AFFIRMATION**

more common nowadays...

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that answers on StackExchange are expected to provide a full explanation, including suitable examples and references. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and to review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use StackExchange, and encourage you to edit your answer and expand it.